# React: async change of global state property

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-redux, state

What is the best way for below scenario?

1. There is a Loader component in App.js which is shown, when a property in global state (redux) property, e.g. loaderOn, is set to true
2. There are couple of async api calls (in different components throughout the app), every which dispatches an action, which shows a loader (loaderOn: true)
3. Problem: how to hide Loader after the LAST request is completed?

a) The above scenario is not quite good - true / false flag turns false after first request is completed

b) I was trying with a counter flag - +1 for each requested started and then -1 for each when completed - Loader hides at 0. But requests are async (and so is setting state from different places?), so it doesn't work either (setting counter flag depends on prev state and so parallel state changes give wrong final value)

Comment: you might just need to have each loading request set a different variable in redux, and then only display the loader if `var1 && var2 && var3`. Alternatively, you could try to look into adding another library on top of redux, see this blog post, it might be helpful: https://www.toptal.com/react-native/react-redux-rxjs-tutorial

Comment: @BillMetcalf, as I answered technophyle - the solution with separete reducer for each loader is not quite what I want - especially, when there are so many loaders. But I will dig into RxJS - although it seems quite complex on first sight. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution to resolve your problem is defining separate loading flags for different async actions.

So, in redux's `initialState`, you can have:

```
{
  ...
  usersLoading: false,
  productsLoading: false,
  companiesLoading: false,
}
```

Then, you set it to `true`/`false` based on the loaded status of each data.

Finally, you can have a selector that evaluates the logical `OR` of all loading flags like this:

```
state.usersLoading || state.productsLoading || state.companiesLoading
```

And in your `App` component, connect the value of that selector to your prop, say, `loading`, and render the `Loader` component based on that:

```
{loading && <Loader />}
```

Comment: Thought about it, but I was looking for something that does not require separate reducer for each request - especially, that there are far more places that use loader than 3, more like 30 ;). Another way I was thinking, was to make a div and add elements by ref for each loader (and for example - show only the first one in css). That would do it, but does not seem like a pretty solution.

Comment: The number of places that use the loader doesn't make things more complicated. You define the selector once, and just use it across all those places, and it will memoize the value if you use reselect, so it'll be the simplest solution in my opinion.